# Difference between PSR-4 and classmap autoloading?

Tags: composer-php, autoload, psr-4

In regards to Laravel, I got a question about Composer autoloading i.e. the difference between "psr-4" and "classmap" autoloading.

1 difference that I know is PSR-4 does not need repeated `dumpautoload` for every changes or addition of new files whereas classmap needs `dumpautoload` for every change in existing files containing classes or addition of new file in specified directory.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

**PSR-4 standard** requires of you a strict filesystem structure based on namespaces. Say you have an app in `src` directory with `App` namespace, then all sub-namespaces will mirror subdirectories and class names will be the same as file names without the `.php` extension.

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "App\\": "src/" }
    }
}

src/
    Foo/
        Bar.php <---- App\Foo\Bar class
    Baz.php <---- App\Baz class
```

The autoloader then "knows" where to look for the class of a certain fully qualified name and therefore doesn't require the dump-autoload command to sniff files for classes.

Performance issues are then solved with `composer dump-autoload --optimize-autoloader` flag, or `-o`, which will generate class map a similar way the classmap autoloading does.

---

On the other hand, **classmap autoloading** does not require you to have almost any certain file or directory structure, it will recursively go through `.php` and `.inc` files in specified directories and files and sniff for classes in them.

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["src/", "lib/", "Something.php"]
    }
}
```

Those classes are then added to a list (cached in a PHP file in vendor/composer directory) which is used for autoloading.

Any new class then must be added to that list by running `composer dump-autoload` command.

Comment: what about plain php files without class? e.g. just a php file with a bunch of global functions, how to add that?

Comment: @Toskan For that, use `files`. Eg, `"autoload": { "files": [ "path/to/file1.php", "another/file.php", "etc.php" ] }`.

Comment: Can classes and files be loaded together, just using the autoload as i have tried this and failed. Both separately fine, but together no dice.

Comment: Sure. Just use classmap/psr/files alongside each other. Autoload/dump will fail on duplicate class FQNs, though. If you have a concrete problem, perhaps create a separate question.